# Spacy download en_core_web_lg manually

Tags: nlp, spacy, language-model, spacy-3

I am trying to find a way to download the  model `en_core_web_lg ==2.3.1` for `Spacy == 2.3.2`.

Currently using

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load ("en_core_web_lg")
```

Is it possible to download the `model file or directory` directly and `load the model` from that downloaded folder.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? That should just work.

Comment: @polm23 it works, but i want to try the other way also.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can.

First, download the model from [here](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/tag/es_core_news_lg-3.1.0). I downloaded the `.tar.gz` format.

Then you extract it and you load it in the code by specifying the path of the wanted subfolders. To be sure that the path is correct, you should get to the folder that contains the `config.cfg` file.

For example:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("your/base/path/en_core_web_sm-3.1.0/en_core_web_sm/en_core_web_sm-3.1.0/")
doc = nlp("This is a sentence.")
```

[Here](https://spacy.io/usage/models#download-manual) you can find some more info.

Comment: I dont have this folder structure in version ```2.3.1```

Comment: Are you using spaCy 2 for a specific reason? Could you maybe switch to version 3?

Comment: Yes I am using this version for a reason.

Comment: Ok, I will look into that in the next days if I have time, in the meanwhile I suggest to search on their [discussion forum](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions), maybe someone else had the same issue

Answer (score 0):

We can download the wheel file from latest releases page [latest releases](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases) and use `pip install <whl_file_path>` to install the model.

Reference: [Spacy download-manual](https://spacy.io/usage/models#download-manual)